# How to set timeouts for long running operations in ASP.NET Core WebListener?

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, weblistener

I would like to set request timeouts for my MVC Controller HTTP Post methods. I am using WebListener.

I've found that if you are using Kestel and IIS you can set request timeout in web.config by specifying requestTimeout attribute on aspNetCore node.

How to do the same with WebListener?
I tried to modify the ListenerSettings (see below) but that didn't work

```
// Use Web listener
var builder =
 new WebHostBuilder().UseConfiguration(config)
 .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
 .UseStartup < Startup > ()
 .UseWebListener(options => {
  options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
  options.ListenerSettings.Timeouts.EntityBody = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
  options.ListenerSettings.Timeouts.DrainEntityBody = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
  options.ListenerSettings.Timeouts.HeaderWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
  options.ListenerSettings.Timeouts.IdleConnection = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
  options.ListenerSettings.Timeouts.RequestQueue = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
  options.ListenerSettings.ThrowWriteExceptions = true;
  options.ListenerSettings.Logger = logger;
 });

var host = builder.Build();
host.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should undo all of those settings because they don't apply to the controller action timeout. There's nothing for that will timeout you controller code specifically. You should be passing a cancellation token to asynchronous methods you'd like to cancel.